# Mint nft on Testnet

Tags: nft, testnets, smart-contract-wallets, opensea

If we can use testnets while verifying your wallet address with smart contract,
e.g.
Rinkeby Robsten vs.

can we use testnet to confirmed opensea account?

Comment: The question is not very clear. Can you add more details about what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

For testnets you can use address https://testnets.opensea.io/